# HTML WYSIWYG editor for php code

Tags: php, html, editor, wysiwyg

i looking javascript editor for php code, include tab support and php code highlight

Comment: Javascript? so you mean something like tinymce, but for php?

Comment: yep, i saw it in a joomla template editor once

Comment: What you mean is a Javascript WYSIWYG editor with PHP syntax highlighling ( and tab support)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not have WYSIWYG but is strictly a code editing plugin for jQuery which supports a number of different languages.  Highly recommended.

[MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/)

I apologize for posting the wrong link!  Forgot the plugin name.

Comment: jEdit is written in Java, not javascript

Comment: I apologize if I misinterpreted your question.  I had thought you were interested in an in browser solution but this might not be the case.  The below answer is sufficient and I also strongly recommend NuSphere's Komodo Edit as one of the best editors.  The highlighting is customizable given a a quick search online.

Comment: i mean javascript editor, can be embedded on web, support php code highlight

Comment: I interpreted the question as requiring a browser-based solution as well -- it's just that the link you provided is not browser based. it's a java application. see http://www.jedit.org/index.php?page=compatibility

Comment: I updated to the correct link for you.

Comment: Wow, markitup is really nice.. but where is the php highlight?

Answer (score 0):

http://wmd-editor.com/ is the editor used by stackoverflow :) Er, you mean an PHP editor, take a look at mozilla bespin: https://bespin.mozilla.com/ And take a closer look at

[PHPanywhere](http://phpanywhere.net/).

It is a Real-time syntax code editor!

Comment: He means an editor for editing php code in browser as far as i can tell, wmd is an HTML wysiwyg editor.

Actually i don't think a wysiwyg editor for php code exists but a code editor with syntax highlighting might. :)